# Lock-in sensitivity and output signal

Tags: amplifier, signal-processing

I am measuring a signal with a lock-in amplifier (SR830) and sending this signal through a GPIB connection to a LabView VI. Should there be a coefficient on the voltage I receive in my VI to read the actual value? (For example, if the sensitivity is set to 10 µV, should I multiply the signal received by LabView by 1E-6?)

Comment: Use a known input signal and decide this yourself is my advice.

Comment: @Andyaka That is a good idea. Do you know how I could generate a signal in the range of microvolts in phase with the lock-in reference signal for testing?

Comment: Just use a resistive divider off the reference output. Make the lower resistance something like 10\$\Omega\$. You can measure the reference output directly.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thanks! I will try this.